# How do I determine if SQL OLE DB drivers are being used?

Tags: sql-server, oledb

Today Azure Defender notified me that some OLE DB drivers are outdated on our two Azure VM's.  However, I wasn't aware these are needed.  Our VM's perform the following duties:

- VM 1: Windows Server 2019 hosting SQL Server 2019, hosting databases for VM 2,
- VM 2: Windows 2019 with IIS, multiple ASP.Net Framework 4.8 web sites all accessing VM 1 databases using exactly the same connection string format: `Server=tcp:10.0.2.4,1433; Persist Security Info=False; Initial Catalog=[SiteXYZ-Db]; User ID=...; Password=...; MultipleActiveResultSets=False; Encrypt=True; TrustServerCertificate=True; Connection Timeout=60`

Doing some initial searching I saw that web sites connecting to SQL via OLE DB would have `Provider=sqloledb;` in the connection string, which we don't see (although I am nervous that's a massive generalisation - perhaps ASP.Net uses this internally?).

Therefore, is there any way to determine whether a driver is being used by other Windows' processes?  The driver is installed on both VM's, and was installed on the date that the VM was commissioned (although I have no recollection of doing this manually and so might have been installed as a by-product of something else?).

Comment: Are you using the Linked Server feature in your SQL Server instance?

Comment: @J.D. No we're not.  Only the ASP.Net applications do CRUD work; no other forms of data manipulation are done.